# PHP array doesn't change to object

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop

I've been trying for hours to change array into the object, but it just doesn't work. However, my second function, where code is almost identical works perfectly.
Here is the class and function:

```
class Job {
private $connection;

function __construct($mysqli){
    $this->connection = $mysqli;
}

function getJobModal() {

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT id, name, description, company, county, parish, location, address FROM job_offers WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $job_id);
    $stmt->bind_result($id_from_db, $name_from_db, $desc_from_db, $company_from_db, $county_from_db, $parish_from_db, $location_from_db, $address_from_db);
    $stmt->execute();

    $array = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $job = new StdClass();
        $job->id = $id_from_db;
        $job->name = $name_from_db;
        $job->description = $desc_from_db;
        $job->company = $company_from_db;
        $job->county = $county_from_db;
        $job->parish = $parish_from_db;
        $job->location = $location_from_db;
        $job->address = $address_from_db;
        array_push($array, $job);
    }
    return $array;

    $stmt->close();



}
}
```

isset, creating a variable, which should make array into object

```
if(isset($_GET["view"])) {
    $Job->getJobModal($_GET["view"]);
} 

$job_single_array = $Job->getJobModal();
```

Asking some objects, i tried different ways, as you can see

```
echo $job_single_array->id;
echo $job_single_array->name;
echo $job_single_array[$i]->company;
echo $job_single_array['id'];
var_dump($job_single_array);
```

Form, note: $job_array is working fine

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($job_array); $i++) {
    echo "<form action='jobs.php' method='get'>";
    echo "<a class='list-group-item' href='?view=".$job_array[$i]->id."'>";
    echo "<h4 class='list-group-item-heading' name='job_id'>".$job_array[$i]->id."</h4>";
    echo "<h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>".$job_array[$i]->name."</h4>";
    echo "<p class='list-group-item-text'>".$job_array[$i]->company.", ".$job_array[$i]->county.", ".$job_array[$i]->parish."</p>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</form>";

}
```

Errors

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../jobs.php on line 105 
Notice: Trying to get   property of non-object in /.../jobs.php on line     106 
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /.../jobs.php on line 107 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../jobs.php on line 107 
Notice: Undefined index: id in /.../jobs.php on line 108 
array(0) { }
```

Comment: The return value from the call to `$Job->getJobModal($_GET["view"]);` isn't being assigned to anything.... and there's not much point in passing `$_GET["view"]` as an argument to `$Job->getJobModal()` either, because you don't do anything with it

Comment: And getJobModal() doesn't accept any parameter... How are you passing $_GET["view "] ? Anyway, can you point us what's written on lines 105/106 ?

Comment: have you tried `(object)$myArray` ?

Comment: Other problems : you're doing $stmt->bind_param("i", $job_id);, but where is $job_id being defined ? You probably have no result, so you have an empty array.

Comment: line 105 and 106 is echo $job_single_array->id;
echo $job_single_array->name;

Comment: You are returning the array from your function not the object!

Comment: Please note that you can also just fetch an object from MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [documentation for `bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch(). Depending on column types bound variables can silently change to the corresponding PHP type.

so just change the order of your lines:

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT id, name, description, company, county, parish, location, address FROM job_offers WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $job_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id_from_db, $name_from_db, $desc_from_db, $company_from_db, $county_from_db, $parish_from_db, $location_from_db, $address_from_db);
```

And they should be available during the `fetch()`.

Also, at this line in your function:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $job_id);
```

It looks like your `$job_id` variable is undefined. Where is it coming from?

Moreover, your function returns an *array*, that's what the var_dump is telling you:

```
var_dump($job_single_array);
// array(0)
// it is of length 0 because your query is failing,
//probably because $job_id is undefined
$job_single_array = $Job->getJobModal();
// this is not true. getJobModal() returns an array
```

use a foreach:

```
foreach ($Job->getJobModal() as $job_single_array) {
    //here use your object
}
```